# why OperationContext.Current is null?

Tags: .net, wcf

At the client I need to call this method:

```
<OperationContract()> <WebMethod()> _
Public Function NotifierSignIn(ByRef url As String, ByVal login As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal sessionGuid As String, ByVal customerGuid As String) As String
    Dim ret = String.Empty
    Return ret
End Function
```

I 'm trying to call it as:

```
//sessionGuid is empty
string url = string.Empty;
string result = ws.NotifierSignIn(ref url, txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Password, sessionGuid, txtCustomerGuid.Text);
```

First what is executed is method at wcf service (.net 3.5):

```
Public Sub New()
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
        New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf CertificateValidationCallBack)
    _errMsgs = ErrorMessages.GetInstance()

    _authHandlerId = SoapHeaderHelper(Of Integer).GetInputHeader("HandlerId")

End Sub
```

And I get error at

```
public object GetInputHeader(string name)
{
    return GetHeader(name, OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders);
}
```

because `OperationContext.Current` is null.

My service is wcf service because I user

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="VB" Service="MyWS.Service1" %>
```

What is interesting I have nothing in fiddler.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT**
Following Marc suggestion (thanks Mark) I've moved initialization of field to propety.
But there is still a problem. It enters to my webmethod , but in it there is next exception, because OperationContext.Current is still null.
To be clear :
at the first line of my webmethod I have :
Dim context=OperationContext.Current
and unfortunately it is null :/

So, there must be another factor.

Here is my app.config at the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyITNotifier.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings />

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50002/MyIT.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap"
        name="Service1Soap1" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <userSettings>
    <MyITNotifier.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="UseAnimation" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SoundFilePath" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="UseCustomSound" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="PlaySound" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="HandlerId" serializeAs="String">
        <value>1</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SessionGuid" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="MyItUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Interval" serializeAs="String">
        <value>2</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RememberUser" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="CustomerGuid" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
    </MyITNotifier.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you remove the constructor, move the code to a method, and call that method from the `NotifierSignIn` - will you still receive this error? I think that the `OperationContext` doesn't exist in the constructor, try to use it in a method.

Comment: Removed my answer (in respect of your edit) - I'm sorry that didn't work, but it seemed a reasonable thing to try. That is... curious.

Comment: @Marc because of you I learned new thing , so thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the client configuration the endpoint address is listed as `http://localhost:50002/MyIT.asmx`. ASMX services aren't WCF services, so if you try to access any WCF service property while running in an ASMX service (the `WebMethod()` declaration in your operation), then they'll be null. Try regenerating the client by pointing the tool (svcutil / Add Service Reference) to the .svc file, not the .asmx one.

Comment: you have right. in every project was svc. only in this was asmx. it wasn't my code, but was my stupid. Thanks :)